# Drawing arrows in pie chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the data frame below, how can I display labels outside the circle with arrows pointing at them?

```
asd <- data.frame(a=c("fs","dfg","gf"), b=c(3,5,6))
ggplot(asd, aes(x="", y= b, fill = factor(a))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =1) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y") + theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(a, sep = " ", b, "%"), x= 1.3, angle = 0))
```

Comment: Check out package ggrepel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

asd <- data.frame(a = c("fs","dfg","gf"), 
                  b = c(3,10,5)) # changed to show that order doesnt matter

asd %>% 
 mutate(prop = b/sum(b)) %>% 
 arrange(desc(a)) %>%
 mutate(lab.ypos = cumsum(prop) - 0.5*prop) %>% 
 
 ggplot(aes(x = "", y = prop, fill = a)) +
 geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "white") +
 coord_polar("y", start = 0, clip = "off")+
 geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = lab.ypos, xend = 2, yend = lab.ypos, colour = a),
              size = 1) +
 geom_label(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = paste(a, scales::percent(prop))),
           x = 2,
           size = 5,
           color = "white") +
 theme_void() +
 theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

For the record: **don't use pie chart**.

There is a reason why doing a pie chart is complicated: you are not supposed to use them.
Bar charts are always better.

Comment: Thanks. But the values are more. I thought of putting them outside with arrows pointing them. In my case, the requirement is a pie chart from the client :) The values are adding upto 360 so.

Comment: okay wait.. I'll try to see what I can do.. But I think you should just group over a certain number of cases for readability. Anyway, don't bend statistics to your clients will ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I found a way to set the text outside without cropping them. Check out my edit. I'll see if I can connect with a line now..

Comment: This is awesome. A line would be really helpful :)

Comment: so well, I found a workaround for that. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks a lot. But we can also remove text background color right?"

Comment: In geom label set colour = "black", fill = "white"

Comment: Is it what you’re looking for? If so, you should accept the answer: it would be more useful for other users too. Otherwise, let me know.