# how to fill pie chart with percentage value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add percent value to this chart to this data frame

```
s<-# Basic piechart
  ggplot(heart, aes(x="", y="", fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
plot(s)
```

Comment: share `heart` with `dput(heart)`

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923181/drawing-arrows-in-pie-chart-with-ggplot2/63923855#63923855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared your data, but your plot code implies that `heart` is a data frame that includes a column labeled `sex` which is either of factor or character class, so this toy data set should suffice to demonstrate.

```r
set.seed(1)
heart <- data.frame(sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 24, TRUE))
```

Your plotting code is actually stacking all the males, then all the females, without counting them, so there is no way for the `geom_text` to know where in this stack it should be plotting. Instead, you need to use the default stat of `geom_bar`, which is `stat = "count"`, then plot the `geom_text` at the appropriate points:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(heart, aes(x = "", fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  geom_text(data = as.data.frame(table(heart$sex)), 
            aes(group = Var1, label = scales::percent(Freq / sum(Freq)), 
              y = Freq, fill = Var1), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void()
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>